# Rstudio: auto search errors in browser

Tags: rstudio

Is it possible to automatically open the browser and search for the first error when it occurs?

For example,

```
library(RSelenium)
driver <- rsDriver(browser=c("chrome"))
```

gives error:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) : 
  Unrecognized content encoding type. libcurl understands deflate, gzip content encodings.
```

Which I then copy and paste into a browser and do a search.  When this happens frequently it takes time doing the copy-paste-search in browser routine.  Is there a way to speed it up in RStudio?

Comment: I am getting the same error. Did you find a fix?